# Hibernate removing child entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have an entity with a OneToMany list, defined as follows:

```
   @OneToMany(
         mappedBy = "fieldId",
         cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
         orphanRemoval = true,
         fetch = FetchType.EAGER
   )
   @org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy(clause = "sequence ASC")
   public List<FieldDefinitionValue> getListOfValues()
   {
      return listOfValues;
   }
```

When I remove an item from the list, it is not getting deleted from the database when I save the parent entity.

I have created a CustomEntityDirtinessStrategy, which could be the reason this does not work as expected.  When checking dirtiness of the parent entity, I report the entity as dirty, even if the only change is a removal of one or more elements in the listOfValues.

In findDirty, I also report listOfValues as dirty.

The dirty = true responses result in undesired behavior (separate from the main question which is why the child entity removal is not working at all) - there is an unnecessary update call to the parent table.  So I suspect I should not be marking the parent entity itself as dirty.  I did that in an effort to make the child entry removal work.

Any idea what may be causing the child removal to fail?

Below is the custom EntityDirtinessStrategy.  I use this with @DynamicUpdate so that Hibernate only includes fields that have actually changed in its update statements.

```
public class EntityDirtinessStrategy implements CustomEntityDirtinessStrategy
{
   private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(EntityDirtinessStrategy.class);

   @Override
   public boolean canDirtyCheck(Object entity, EntityPersister persister, Session session)
   {
      return entity instanceof DirtyAware;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isDirty(Object entity, EntityPersister persister, Session session)
   {
      return entity instanceof DirtyAware && ((DirtyAware)entity).isDirty();
   }

   @Override
   public void resetDirty(Object entity, EntityPersister persister, Session session)
   {
      if (entity instanceof DirtyAware)
         ((DirtyAware)entity).commitFields();
   }

   @Override
   public void findDirty(Object entity, EntityPersister persister, Session session, DirtyCheckContext dirtyCheckContext)
   {
      if (!(entity instanceof DirtyAware)) return;
      DirtyAware dirtyAware = (DirtyAware)entity;
      dirtyCheckContext.doDirtyChecking(
            attributeInformation -> {
               String propertyName = attributeInformation.getName();
               boolean dirty = dirtyAware.getDirtyFields().contains(propertyName);
               if (dirty) log.debug("Property "+propertyName+" is dirty.");
               return dirty;
            }
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: How does CustomEntityDirtinessStrategy look like? And why do you need that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined what the problem is here.  What I did not say, because I did not realize it mattered, is that on my `setX (List list)` method (for property X), I was not simply storing the list and then passing it back on the `getX` method.

Instead I had copied the contents from that list into my local list.

Hibernate requires that entities use the setX collection directly, because it implements all of the persistence logic in the collection implementation it provides.  I devised an alternative method to check dirtiness of the collection (not necessary for persistence, but rather to identify to my UI code whether the entity was modified by the user.)  And then revised the code to accept and return the Hibernate collection in the setX and getX methods.  Now it works.